# Control Panel to host java based sites

Tags: linux, java, control-panel, windows-server-2008

i am new to web hosting and want to know something about it. I have 2 dedicated servers with full control over them 1 with Linux (CentOS5.5) other with Windows 2008 server

Please suggest me some FREE web panel that helps in website hosting and support features like ftp, creating multiple users and should support JAVA based sites(war), PHP and Drupal. and should have e-commerce features included.

Comment: You're new to hosting, but are maintaining two dedicated servers based on vastly different operating systems? You might want to slow down a little bit.

Comment: ya i use them for game server hosting.. but can use it for site hosting as well just came 2 know it today.... :P

Answer (score 2):

**There are many free control panels alternatives to cpanel heres 9 take your pick**

- [Webmin](http://www.webmin.com/)
- [Web CP](http://www.web-cp.net/)
- [Flex CP](http://flexcp.sourceforge.net/)
- [SysCP](http://freecode.com/projects/syscp)
- [ISPConfig 3](http://www.ispconfig.org/ispconfig-3/)
- [Virtualmin](http://www.virtualmin.com/)
- [Ehcp](http://ehcp.net/)
- [Zpanel](http://www.zpanelcp.com/)
- [Kloxo](http://lxcenter.org/software/kloxo)