# Chrome Extension or online tool to access and edit files on server via FTP/other protocols

Tags: web-development, ftp

I recently got a Chromebook Pixel, and find it to be a great alternative laptop to my Macbook Pro, especially for non coding tasks like email etc.

I was wondering if there was any IDE style extension or web app that I can use to access my server via FTP or some other protocol, which would allow me to view and edit the backend files (PHP, HTML, images and so on) and upload them back when I hit save. This would allow me to edit and develop my website without starting up the MacBook Pro, which can be quite slow due to all the other stuff I run on it.

I was looking for either an extension that plugs straight into Chrome, or something along the lines of [eXtplorer](http://extplorer.sourceforge.net/), which is a PHP based file manager for servers. It has some of these features inbuilt, and can edit files, but is quite slow and doesn't have stuff like code autocompletion.

Answer (score 1):

**Web Administration Control Panels**

You can do this on the server level rather (PHP File Manager) than using an extension - all you need is a web control panel such as directadmin or cpanel which I know these support these features you have listed, these however cost money - most shared hosting will provide cpanel free of charge. If you operate your own server and want to keep costs down then here is free alternatives to [cpanel](http://cpanel.net/) and [directadmin](http://www.directadmin.com/) but I'm unable to comment if these support this feature but you can investigate further:

> **[There are many free control panels alternatives to cpanel heres 9 take your pick](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/43758/20604)**
>
> - [Webmin](http://www.webmin.com/)
> - [Web CP](http://www.web-cp.net/)
> - [Flex CP](http://flexcp.sourceforge.net/)
> - [SysCP](http://freecode.com/projects/syscp)
> - [ISPConfig 3](http://www.ispconfig.org/ispconfig-3/)
> - [Virtualmin](http://www.virtualmin.com/)
> - [Ehcp](http://ehcp.net/)
> - [Zpanel](http://www.zpanelcp.com/)
> - [Kloxo](http://lxcenter.org/software/kloxo)

**PHP File Managers**

You can also edit files online from any computer using the browser using a php file manager that is installed on your website, such as:

- [phpFileManager](http://phpfm.sourceforge.net/)
- [ajaxplorer](http://ajaxplorer.info/)
- [FileThingie](http://www.solitude.dk/filethingie/)
- [KFM Manager](http://kfm.verens.com/)
- [eXtplorer](http://extplorer.sourceforge.net/)
- [BytesFall Explorer](http://bfexplorer.sourceforge.net/)
- [PHPfileNavigator](http://pfn.sourceforge.net/)
- [QuiXplorer](http://quixplorer.sourceforge.net/)
- [NavPHP](http://navphp.sourceforge.net/)

**Inline HTML Editors**

Another option could be that you use inline HTML editors such as:

> [Dynamic Content Editor](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/44462/20604)
>
> 1. [CKEditor](http://cpanel.net/)
> 2. [TinyMCE](http://www.directadmin.com/)
> 3. [Aloha Editor](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/43758/20604)
> 4. [NicEdit](http://www.webmin.com/)
> 5. [Snippetedit](http://www.web-cp.net/)
> 6. [Wymeditor](http://flexcp.sourceforge.net/)
> 7. [PimenTech-scripts : jquery.jframe.js](http://freecode.com/projects/syscp)
> 8. [Jeditable](http://www.ispconfig.org/ispconfig-3/)
> 9. [jQuery Editable](http://www.virtualmin.com/)
> 10. [Edit in Place With Ajax Using jQuery JavaScript](http://ehcp.net/)
> 11. [Table Editor](http://www.zpanelcp.com/) (Useful for Editable Tables)
> 12. [jQuery Plugin: Inline Text Edit](http://lxcenter.org/software/kloxo)
> 13. [Ajax Instant Edit](http://phpfm.sourceforge.net/)
> 14. [JeIP](http://ajaxplorer.info/)

Answer (score 1):

A quick google search returned a couple of cloud based IDEs.

- [Cloud9 IDE](https://c9.io/)
- [ShiftEdit](https://shiftedit.net/)
- [Compilr](https://compilr.com/)

I have not tested them, from the looks of it Cloud9 seem to support ftp right out of the box. If you're looking for a chrome extension with advanced features such as code auto-completion you might be out of luck. There are ftp extensions but I haven't heard of a full fledged IDE as a extension.
Also at least to me there is little point in having a complete IDE as a chrome extension, extension weren't designed to be used as full fledged "programs".

Edit: The open source editor [Brackets](http://brackets.io/) also looks promising.